# base system driver missing

Tags: windows-7, windows

I re-installed Windows 7 and I currently have 3 Base System Devices with a yellow exclamation which means it's unrecognized and the drivers for it are missing.

Windows update has been unable to find the missing drivers for the device and I can't figure out what the device could be.

I have a hp compaq presario v3000. What could the Base System Device be?

Comment: Open preferences and find `Hardware ID` in details of that device, it looks like this `PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_1C03`, post it for each device.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and in my case the driver for the card reader was missing and now Windows shows this "Base System Device". So install the driver (if possible) or disable the device if you can't find a driver.